# Change font for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion and I need to set the font family to a custom font for a button in the navigation bar (UIBarButtonItem). I know I do it like this in Objective-C but how is it done in Ruby?

```
[buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Thankful for all help!

Comment: just curious. Why Rubymotion instead of Xcode? because of the Objective-C learning curve?

Comment: I know Ruby very good (Rails developer) and I see no reason to use Objective-C since the outcome from both Rubymotion and Objective-C is exactly the same.

Comment: just discussion: Rubymotion can't build Interface easily, right? (need to build via 100% codes only, i.e. no drag & drop)

Comment: No, you can use both Storyboards and Nib files. They are compiled automatically with Rubymotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it.  I don't have my Mac handy to test this out so give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

```
buttonItem.setTitleTextAttributes({UITextAttributeFont => UIFont.fontWithName("Helvetica-Bold", size:26.0)}, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your AppDelegate use something like this

```
NSDictionary *itemTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Regular" size:18],NSFontAttributeName,
                                    nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:itemTextAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```